# Validation Rule to check PRIORVALUE

Tags: apex, trigger, validation, validation-rule

I am writing one validation rule where status is Pending/In Progress and I am changing any value from record then I need to throw an error 'you cannot edit the record'.

```
AND(OR( ISPICKVAL( Status , 'Pending'), 
ISPICKVAL( Status , 'InProgress'))
```

The issue here it's not allow me to set status Pending at all..then i Added

```
OR( AND( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"Pending"),ISPICKVAL( Status , 'Pending')), 
 AND( ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),"InProgress"),ISPICKVAL( Status , 'InProgress')))
```

Again the issue is when I Set status from suppose Review to Pending then it will save. which is correct, and then if I try to edit record then it will be thrown an error.
 but when I am changing the value from Pending to something else like Complete then it should not be thrown an error, but because of PRIORVALUE() its throwing error.

Please suggest

Comment: Your second validation rule look corrects to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second validation rule should suffice your needs.

But if it's still giving you an error, then can you check

- If you have any triggers on that object
- If Yes, then check if you are updating the status back to Pending/InProgress in your before insert/update code

If the answer for above two questions is Yes, then that might be the reason you are getting that error from validation rule.

Answer (score 1):

you want to add exception, that you can change Status from `InProgress` to `Pending`:

```
OR(
    AND(
        ISPICKVAL(Status  'Pending'),
        NOT(ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(Status),'InProgress'))
    ),
    ISPICKVAL(Status , 'InProgress')
)
```

Comment: but here when i am changing value from Pending to some other then it should save

Comment: @sam can you formalize your validation rule  ? e.g prevent from editing record, once Status= 'pending' or Status='InProgress' or.... but allow to change status at any time.

Comment: not yet.facing issues on above validation